# Gnome Shell Grey Screen No Login Box After AMD Drivers Installation On Lubuntu

Tags: gnome, ati, xorg, fglrx

I installed the fglrx AMD drivers on Lubuntu and rebooted.  The machine didn't reboot properly and I could only see a prompt.  I logged in and uninstalled the drivers using

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```

I then issued the command

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and then

```
sudo reboot
```

The machine now boots but only to a grey gnome shell screen that doesn't show me the login window with my username and a sign in button.  Just a blank grey screen.

How can I fix this and also get the fglrx drivers working?

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Ctrl + F2

`sudo apt-get remove amdcccle*`

`sudo startx`

If sudo startx doesn't work it's not a big deal

`sudo apt-get install cdbs dh-mak dkms execstack dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic libqtgui4 gksu`

If 64-bit version of Ubuntu add `lib32gcc1` to the list above

`sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle`

or if you prefer the latest use this instead `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fgrlx-amdcccle-updates`

`sudo aticonfig --initial` or a dual gpu setup `aticonfig --initial --adapter=all`

### `sudo reboot`

`try doing sudo aticonfig --initial` and add your second gpu to the xorg.conf using nano and check your BIOS, if there is an option for integrated graphics, set it to Auto, not Force. I have noticed that its easier to setup dual-gpus with the driver directly from AMD, but your still going to have to edit the config file before try `adapter=all`, if both are not listed in `fglrxinfo` and I really think not forcing it in BIOS is key, but I have a Gigabyte mobo, I don't know if every mobo has that option, but if you are using 2 cards, instead of and apu and a discrete graphics card, maybe that is the issue, the cchtml guide says not to us 2 cards in crossfire, are you trying to use one monitor, but get use to cards, or use multiple monitors? I know you are mining lightcoin with one gpu, you can use the other for graphics.

Comment: I have done all of this and I followed those guides multiple times and everything gets installed.  

When I run the command sudo aticonfig --initial --adapter=all and reboot the system then it will not start the GUI.

It boots to the Lubuntu splash screen and either stays on that screen or shows an error about "Xorg Tainted" after about 10 minutes.  

During this time I can ssh into the machine but the GUI is irretrievably broken at this point because the aticonfig command which modifies xorg.conf.


Where can I go from here because these drivers simply do not work?

Comment: After having removed the drivers and xorg.conf modified file the grey screen returns randomly after rebooting.

Comment: try doing sudo aticonfig --initial

Comment: I have two graphics cards installed so I want to configure both of them.  I think I have to do the sudo aticonfig --initial --adapter=all when using more than one graphics card but I have already tried this and when I reboot the GUI doesn't work.

Comment: do you have them hooked up to each other to use in crossfire? If so check out the aticonfig --help, and it has commands to link them together and enable them in crossfire. there is also a command in the wiki.cchtml for grey screen problems as well as hang on boot. But, when I can't get past the splash screen I change the graphics card settings in my bios. to safely reboot you can Atl + Ctrl + F2, then Atl + Ctrl + Del. Also, even if you don't see both in fglrxinfo, you should see both in aticonfig --lsa, if you are still having problems, consider uninstalling and getting the driver from AMD

Comment: Also, I was wrong earlier you have to do `sudo apt-get remove --purger fglrx* fglrx-amdcccle*` otherwise if you have fglrx, it will remove that and install fglrx-updates

Comment: When I remove fglrx then fglrxinfo command does not work. I hadn't looked into Crossfire yet because both cards don't consistently appear when I boot whether the drivers are installed or not.  Should I disconnect the cards and install the drivers or install the drivers while the cards are connected?

Comment: Ideally I want to use the integrated graphics so when I boot the monitor is attached to that graphics card.  Then the two additional R9 280x's can be used for mining litecoins.  Currently both R9 280x's do not appear at the same time even though both are connected.  Even when I issue lspci command usually only one GPU shows up.

Comment: Make sure your default graphics is the integrated graphics by disconnecting or turning of the gpu cards in bios and having your monitor plugged into the integrated card. Install and restart make sure your install was good, (if you don't have a amd apu maybe that's a problem?) But, then do adapter=all -f  and plugin or turn on your gpu in bios forcing integrated. (diff solutions for diff uses). When I was doing litecoin with my gpu, I used Cryptobadgers guide. Litecoin.info > tutorials > Cryptobadger2. But, maybe set up you mining operation before you reboot to make the gpus in use.

Comment: Still battling with this. Now I have successfully installed the drivers through apt-get and when I boot/reboot I can see both GPU's. But when I run sudo aticonfig --initial it says "command not found" even though fglrx was successfully installed.

Comment: I really don't think it was successfully installed then.